# PowerShell : retrieve JSON object by variable value

Tags: powershell

```
$json = ConvertFrom-Json "{key:true}"
$key = "key"
Write-Host $json[$key]
```

I'd like that to print true but it doesn't. I know `$json.key` would work. Can this be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know that `$json.key` would work, then why you're switching from dot to square brackets?
All these will work:

```
$json = ConvertFrom-Json "{key:true}"
$key = "key"

Write-Host $json.$key
Write-Host $json.$($key)
Write-Host $json."$key"
```

Comment: `key` is read from somewhere else. `$json.$key` works nicely... I had no idea PS could understand that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could be referencing it using dot notation with your variables.

```
$json.$key
```

So in your Write-Host you would need a subexpression if you used quotes in your write-host

```
Write-Host "Key is: $($json.$key)"
```

You were trying to use array notation and returning null.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.. really. It let me know I made a mistake in typing.